# How do I forward nginx requests to a specific upstream/backend based on request body?

Tags: nginx, routing, reverse-proxy

I have a few upstreams and am interested in determining which to `proxy_pass` a request to based on a combination of query params and a field in the body JSON.

My question is essentially:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  location / {
    if ( $arg_operation = "someValue" ) { proxy_pass http://upstream1; }
    # Here's where I'm not so sure; I want to do something like this
    if ( $body_value ~ "/shibboleth: true/" ) { proxy_pass http://upstream2; }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I've heard you can use lua/js to do some more custom stuff, which might apply here?

Comment: The request body is in the variable `$request_body`. You haven't really given a good example of what you want to do, so maybe that's all that you need?

Comment: What I want is simply to be able to route to an upstream (microservice) based on a field in a (JSON) POST body as well as a query parameter in GETs. I imagine I could regex against the whole body text, but that might not be the most optimal way to go about this. Thanks for the $request_body variable name ;)

Comment: nginx only cares about HTTP protocol structures, and request body is just a single bytestream from nginx point of view. So, there isn't anything else for your JSON field matching available. Lua could be used to work on the request body. However, I suggest using some HTTP header for this information, encoding such data in the request body is not a good approach.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen alas, I'm bound by backwards compatability needs as this'll be fronting an existing set of APIs with existing clients in the wild. Newer clients will have headers we can use, but some of the oldest ones probably won't. The issue is that we have an ecosystem of APIs with varying protocols which want to talk to the same 'endpoint'.

Answer (score 0):

Working example that maybe can help whoever lands here:
https://github.com/ericminio/learning-nginx/tree/master/payload_filter

```
map $request_body $matching {
    default       'not_matching';
    include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/matching;
}

server {                                                                              
    default_type  text/plain;

    location /ping {
        return 200 'pong';
    }

    location / {  
        proxy_set_header 'X-Matching' $matching;
        proxy_pass http://localhost/routing;           
    } 

    location /routing {
        try_files /unknown-file-to-trigger-redirect @_$http_x_matching;
    }
    location @_matching {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5015;
    }
    location @_not_matching {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5066;
    } 

}
```